# Tooltips Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am working to show tool tip (Help Overlay) for Android.

Actually, I have an activity with view pager and view pager is having `Fragments`. One of the fragment has `RecyclerView` with `Grid Layout`.

I have to show tool tip for the items in this `grid view`.

I want to access the view holder of the particular item in the grid view of the `fragment` of the view pager in Main activity.

How to achieve that?

Main Activity (parent)
        Home Fragment (1st child) (contains images (in the Grid Layout of Recyclerview (homeRecyclerView)) of basic actions of the app)
        Family Fragment (2nd Child) (contains family details)
        History Fragment (3rd Child) (contains details about sessions created)

In the main activity or in Home `Fragment`, for each of the Item in the homeRecyclerView, I have to show the tool tip. I need to have access to the `ViewHolder` of each of this item to show the tool tip. What is the best method to get hold of View holder?

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best method to get hold of View holder?

Not getting it at all. You should not stick your fingers that deep from Activity code - all you should know there is "I got recyclerview here". All the implementation details should be completely hidden.

What you should do instead is to tell your `RecyclerView` to show a tooltip for row number X, which in turn should result either in `RecyclerView`'s code doing that tooltip or "forwarding" your request to the row view for action (depends on what structure it is).

Answer (score 0):

You should add an on click listener to the view holder item and pass it to the fragment by the adapter interface. After that your are able to intercept the behaviour and respond to it. If you want to control everything from the main activity you should create another interface in the viewe pager fragment to pass to the main activity